# Microsoft SQL Server 2005 cast bigint to string

Tags: sql-server, casting

How can I cast a bigint variable to a string?

```
DECLARE @id bigint
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
select CAST(@id as varchar(max))
```

Comment: When running `select CAST(@@DBST AS varchar(max))` I get the proper result within SQL MGMT STUDIO but when I use `DBI` (perl) to bring back the result - it gives me ☼á (whatever that is...).

But when I try `select cast(cast(@@DBTS AS bigint) AS varchar)` I get `4000` - even though the real value should be 339215. Any idea what I can do to correct this?

Comment: Figured it out! As it turns out - I needed to set the database for which I wanted the sequence number. The 4000 was coming from the "default" database. FYI: To set the database, simply add: `use DATABASENAME;` followed by your query `SELECT cast(@@DBTS as bigint)`